# MariaDB/MySQL - How to query JSON based on key of nested object

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

Given the following JSON object stored in MariaDB/MySQL:

```
SET @j = '{
    "thing": {
        "sub_things": [
            {
                "attribute": [
                    { "1": 40 },
                    { "5": 25 },
                    { "13": 35 }
                ]
            },
            {
                "attribute": [
                    { "2": 50 },
                    { "7": 50 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

How would I query this to return `sub_things` where one of the objects in the `attribute` array has a particular key e.g. where the key is 13 this should return the first `sub_thing`.

Thanks!

Comment: While it is _possible_, hiding things that you want to search for in `JSON` is not necessarily the best design of the schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if in a single query you can achieve what you need.

The following stored procedure, perhaps, can give you some ideas (stored procedure works for MariaDB and for MySQL):

```sql
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `JSON_query_based_on_key`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

> DELIMITER //

> CREATE PROCEDURE `JSON_query_based_on_key`(
->   `json` TEXT,
->   `key` VARCHAR(5)
-> )
-> BEGIN
->   DECLARE `sub_things_current` INT
->      DEFAULT JSON_LENGTH(`json`, '$.thing.sub_things') - 1;
-> 
->   WHILE (`sub_things_current` > -1) DO
->     IF NOT JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(
->       `json`, 
->       'one', 
->       CONCAT('$.thing.sub_things[', `sub_things_current`, '].attribute[*]."', `key`, '"')
->     ) THEN
->       SET `json` := JSON_REMOVE(
->         `json`,
->         CONCAT('$.thing.sub_things[', `sub_things_current`, ']'));
->     END IF;
->     SET `sub_things_current` := `sub_things_current` - 1;
->   END WHILE;
-> 
->   SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`json`, '$.thing');
-> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

> DELIMITER ;

> CALL `JSON_query_based_on_key`('{
'>   "thing": {
'>     "sub_things": [
'>       {
'>         "attribute": [
'>           { "1": 40 },
'>           { "5": 25 },
'>           { "13": 35 }
'>         ]
'>       },
'>       {
'>         "attribute": [
'>           { "2": 50 },
'>           { "7": 50 }
'>         ]
'>       }
'>     ]
'>   }
'> }', '13');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(`json`, '$.thing')                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"sub_things": [{"attribute": [{"1": 40}, {"5": 25}, {"13": 35}]}]} |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Modify the code as you need it.

See [db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4c93e684d9d8c98ff3537ddbabcbe823) for MariaDB (10.2.6) and [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3JnwLkyAkNYN3bxuitfBzX/1) for MySQL (5.7.17).

Comment: Excellent answer!!